# Disabling automatic capturing of C++ exceptions in Googletest unittests

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

Is there a way to disable automatic capturing of C++ exceptions when running unittests with Google test? This in order to get better context of the origin of an error.

Comment: `--gtest_catch_exceptions=0` should do the trick, that's how it's tested [in Googletest source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gtest/+/86dec5c00225b34a0061127e5cc35b6cf1485b79/test/gtest_catch_exceptions_test.py#44)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You can submit this as an answer.

Comment: I'm currently developing these tests using a CMake-based build system (catkin) for ROS (robot operating system). Is there a way to feed the flag `--gtest_catch_exceptions=..` as flag to the CMake/Make call or a setting inside the `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

As **Yksisarvinen** mentioned, by invoking the test executable with `--gtest_catch_exceptions=0` you should be able to keep googletest from catching exceptions (if that is what you want - the test application will probably crash messily instead).

That said, it depends on what you want to achieve:
In my test suits I make sure to encapsulate functions that `throw()` exceptions in a try-catch block so I can quickly determine what went wrong (if/when they fail), and (if necessary) then manually check the issue with a debugger.

Comment: Just noting that GTest does not do a good job catching exceptions. If a test case throws any exception, I see gtest print: unknown file: error, even if the exception has nothing to do with a file.

Comment: It is easy to misunderstand: "unknown file: error" does not mean "you tried to do something with an (unknown) file and that caused the error" but rather "I cannot tell in which file the exception was thrown". As I mentioned before, wrap your testcase in try/catch block (and pipe the what() of the exception into FAIL() ) - this will make your life much easier